# Django template: iterating through dictionary wont show values

Tags: django

I have dictionary in my django template. When i simply output it using {{ x.servicestate }} it will print its contents into html:

```
[{'efefefef': 'blad'}, {'efef': 'blad'}, {'eerer': 'blad'}, {'aaa': 'blad'}, {'b': 'blad'}, {'ererer': 'blad'}]
```

But when i use this to iterate:

```
 {% for key,value in x.service_state %}

        {{ key }}<br>{{ value }}

 {% endfor %}
```

It will only output its keys:

```
efefefef
efef
eerer
aaa
b
ererer
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You want iterate the `dict`, so you need to handle it. Try doing this:

For this list:

```
[{'efefefef': 'blad'}, {'efef': 'blad'}, {'eerer': 'blad'}, {'aaa': 'blad'}, {'b': 'blad'}, {'ererer': 'blad'}]
```

Let's call it `blah`

```
{% for b in blah %}
    {% for k, v in b.items %}
        {{ k }}, {{ v }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```